# Is it possible to work with the Podio iOS app from other apps? I.e. open Podio and show a specific entry in an app

Tags: ios, podio

We are in the process of creating an app that communicates with Podio.

During the work flow, we would like our app to open up the Podio iOS app and show a specific entry in one of the apps/tables of Podio.

Is it possible to work with the Podio iOS in such a way?
Can we trigger opening of Podio and navigation inside the app, from outside the app with APIs or similar?

Hope someone can help with any input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Podio iOS will open (or at least offer end-user option to open) links that starts with https://podio.com/*. This is exactly the way to go directly to Podio item from your email (for example), when you received mail notification. So, if you know your item URL, try opening it by system app, and iOS should let Podio app open it.

That won't work for any Podio url, but only for task, status, item urls.